# How can the evaluation queue be aborted?

Tags: front-end

While developing, I would sometimes like to stop evaluation of selected cells at a certain point.  The following example nearly seems to work, but repeated runs of `Ctrl+A, Enter` reveal something sticking in memory.  Is there a good way break out of the evaluation queue?

```
Print["1"]

Print["2"]

FrontEndExecute@FrontEndToken["EvaluatorAbort"]

Print["3"]

Print["4"]
```

*Example of the problem:*

On the fourth repetition (on this occasion) of `Ctrl+A, Enter` the first cell does not evaluate.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As far I can tell the erratic behavior you report is only produced by the first cell in the notebook. For example, with

```
1 + 1
2 + 2
Print[1]
FrontEndExecute@FrontEndToken["EvaluatorAbort"]
Print[2]
Print[3]
```

the result of `1 + 1` behaves erratically under repeated evaluation of the whole expression sequence, but the result of `2 + 2` is always OK. I suggest you put a "don't care" expression into the first notebook cell as s work-around.

#### Edit

Since using "EvaluatorAbort" is unreliable, perhaps the following will be more satisfactory:

```
Print[1]
FrontEndExecute@FrontEndToken["EvaluatorQuit"]
Print[2]
Print[3]
```

It seems to work reliably, but incurs the extra overhead of a "Do you really want to ..." dialog and the of time needed to restart the kernel.

Comment: Thanks, but that still not great.  After the abort any cell might be chosen for evaluation, with no telling whether it will evaluate or not.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen. Don't understand your comment. Suggest you make it as edit to your question with an example of how it impacts your problem.

Comment: ... for instance, after evaluating the notebook with `Ctrl+A, Enter` the next cell I want to evaluate could be `Print[3]`, but it may or may not evaluate.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen. I think I see what you are getting at now. However, if the cell you attempt to evaluate after the abort fails to evaluate the first time, it seems to always evaluate on a second try. However, I would agree that `FrontEndExecute@FrontEndToken[EvaluatorAbort]` appears to leave the kernel in a strange state.