# Any way to eliminate evaluating cells except for "Abort evaluation"?

Tags: evaluation, notebooks, syntax, abort

I have a notebook with many cells, one of which contains an evaluation of some condition. If it is `False`, I want to have an automatized way of the "Abort evaluation" button. However, I have not found such a realization.

For instance, `Abort[]` does not work (even for the same cell). Say, consider two cells, one

```
Abort[]
fff = y
```

and another one

```
ggg=z
```

Let us evaluate the two (the one with `Abort[]` first). It turns out that everything below `Abort[]` is still evaluated.

Is there any way to code the analog of "Abort evaluation"?

Comment: Could you please give an explicit example?

Comment: @MarcoB : I have added an example.

Comment: Seems similar: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27758/how-can-the-evaluation-queue-be-aborted

Comment: I don't know if there's a newer answer but this seems to do what you and topic linked by @Goofy ask for: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/99582/5478 (you don't need $AssertFunction:=, but that is the function that needs to executed instead of Abort)